# does H2 support chaining posgtreSQL WITH clauses ? (h2:2.2.224)

Tags: postgresql, h2, quarkus

I'm currently working on a **Java 17 Quarkus 3.6.9 application with a PostgreSQL database** and writing tests using an embedded H2 database.

One of the PostgreSQL queries I'm using looks like this:

```sql
with optim as (
    select A, B, C from table1
),
filteredTable2 as (
    select optim.A, optim.B, optim.C, t2.E, t2.F 
    from table2 t2 
    inner join optim on t2.D = optim.A
),
sumedTable2 as (
    select A, sum(E), sum(F) 
    from filteredTable2 
    group by A
)
select ft2.A, ft2.B, ft2.C, ft2.E, ft2.F 
from filteredTable2 ft2 
inner join sumedTable2 st2 on ft2.A = st2.A
```

This query might not look very useful, the main **take away is the usage of chained WITH clauses**, the *content of each SELECT is meaningless* in this example.

As I'm attempting to test this with H2, I keep getting empty results from my query, **despite inserting all the necessary data for it to function**.

I looked up the version of H2 that we're using and noticed that the change log mentions a fix to make this feature I'm needing functional:

[Link to the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3675)

[Link to the H2 changelog:](https://www.h2database.com/html/changelog.html)

so i upgraded to the latest version :

```
    // Unit-test frameworks
    testImplementation "io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5"
    testImplementation ('com.h2database:h2'){
        version  {
            strictly('2.2.224')
        }
    }
    testImplementation "io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-h2"
    testImplementation "io.quarkus:quarkus-test-h2"
    testImplementation "com.ninja-squad:DbSetup:2.1.0"
```

The library is downloaded and fully functional, but the issue persists. I also tried using the PostgreSQL compatibility mode:

`URL: jdbc:h2:mem:cga;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING=HIGH;`

However, when I try to query the data using H2, I get an empty result. Strangely, when I use PostgreSQL, it works fine.

To me, it seems like either there is something I'm missing in configuring H2, or the library might not support this syntax.

Did anybody run through a similar issue after the H2 fix was released ?
ps: i'm not looking for workarounds, if we can't fix this using H2, then the issue will escalate.

**EDIT**
Temporary fix: in my init.sql i created view that recreate the with statements, it works, it's dirty but it's enough to bypass the issue.

Perma fix: we moved from h2 to a postgres docker image.

Comment: CTEs are broken in recent versions of H2, so you either need to compile H2 from the current sources and use this self-compiled version, or you can try some older version of H2.